# Where is the syntax `while IFS= read line` documented?

Tags: bash, shell

Why does every example I see have `while IFS= read line` and not `while IFS=; read line`?

I thought that `name=value command` might set a local variable but `sentence="hello" echo $sentence`doesn't work, while `sentence="hello"; echo $sentence` does.

Comment: For documentation on `read`, in your terminal, presumable in `bash`, run `help read`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The:

```
name=value command
```

syntax sets the `name` to `value` for the `command`. In your example:

```
$ sentence="hello" echo $sentence
```

the $sentence is expanded by the calling shell, which does not see the setting. If you do

```
$ sentence="hello" sh -c 'echo $sentence'
```

(note the single quotes to have the `$` expanded by the called shell) it will echo `hello`. And if you try

```
$ sentence="hello"; sh -c 'echo $sentence'
```

it will not echo anything, because `sentence` is set in the current shell, but *not* in the called one, since it was not exported. So

```
IFS=; read line
```

will *not* work, because `read` will *not* see the `IFS` setting.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the real question .i.e about the documentation.

Answer (score 7):

Prefixing a command with parameter assignment affects the **environment** of the command being executed.

In `man bash`:

> The environment for any simple command or function may be
>   augmented
>   temporarily by prefixing it with parameter assignments, as
>   described
>   above in PARAMETERS.  These assignment statements affect only the 
>   environment seen by that command.

In your example: `sentence="hello" echo $sentence`, `sentence` will be in the environment of the `echo` command (try this to show yourself: `sentence=HI env | fgrep sentence`), but not in the shell from which you are calling it, which would be required to pass it as an argument to `echo` as you are attempting.