# What is this adddate function doing in this code?

Tags: bash, shell

Can anyone please help me out in explaining what is this `adddate()` function doing exactly in this piece of code? Can anyone tell me line by line especially the `while IFS=read -r line` part.

What are the 3 or more problems with this script?

What is a better/different way to solve this task?

Thanks a lot guys!

```
#!/bin/bash 

adddate() {
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        echo "$(date) $line"
    done
}

for file in $( find /tmp/ -type f -mtime +5 -name '*.fish.temp' )
do
    ls -la $file | adddate >> /tmp/clean.log
done

find /tmp/ -type f -mtime +5 -name '*.fish.temp' | xargs rm

exit 0
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`adddate` is a [**bash shell function**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions) used bellow to pipe the output of `ls` with the intent to prepend the date before the line so it creates a new `clean.log` with date included (date of the time this script ran, and not the time of the actual log - **this may be your 1st issue**)

```
ls -la $file | adddate >> /tmp/clean.log
```

**2nd** - `while IFS=read -r line` issue has been explained on [stackoverflow/6830735](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830735/where-is-the-syntax-while-ifs-read-line-documented)

**3d issue** - I would say is duplicating the `find` command. I would execute the `find` command once, as depending on the folder recursivity, may take some time.

**4th issue** might be the fact that `exit 0` is useless as all sucess process outputs exit with `0` by default (so is redundant)

**5th issue** is an optimization that can be made to find:

```
find /tmp/ -type f -mtime +5 -name '*.fish.temp' | xargs rm
```

so that it executes in oneline lik:

```
find /tmp/ -type f -mtime +5 -name '*.fish.temp' -exec rm {} \;
```

> An **bash alias** is nothing but the shortcut to commands - [more](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-aliases-mac-centos-linux-unix.html)

**UPDATE-1:**

> what is the "-r" argument for"

Also on [`man read`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/read/) (*thanks to [urbanespaceman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8147165/urbanespaceman)*), it means that if you have in your stream (string), something like `\n` to be interpreted like 2 characters (`\` and `n`, and not the special character `newline`.

```
-r        Do not treat a <backslash> character in any special way. Consider each <backslash> to be part of the input line.
```

**UPDATE-2:**

> is there any security issues with this script?

I guess depends how is used and how often. You're appending to the `*.fish.temp` so, you can go easily out of space if abused. Also, you're removing from your system whatever is there. You are also `exit 0`, regardless how `find` or any command there exited. Is that what you want?

Comment: thanks so much dear. But for the 2nd issue, "while IFS=read -r line"  what is the "-r" argument for" ?  is it reading a line in reverse or what?

Comment: is there any security issues with this script as well do you think?

Comment: The -r is disallowing escape slashes. See the man page: http://www.linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html

Answer (score 1):

1. It's looking for a list of all files under /tmp/ that were modified within the last 5 days and are called ".fish.temp"
2. For each of these files it is writing them line by line to /tmp/clean.log, prepending the timestamp from the `date` command. (The `-la` really isn't needed here though I don't think).
3. Then it runs the same `find` command and runs the results through `rm` to delete the files.
4. Finally it exits with a success code.

Step 3 is dodgy actually, as the find command could potentially return different results, depending on how often files in that dir are added/changed, how long the process takes to run, etc. This should be included in the for loop.

IFS defines the seperator - when set to blank it will just be end of line.

Comment: is there any security issues with this script as well do you think?

Comment: I'm not a security expert, but I don't see any. I guess it depends on the contents of the files, the user that runs the script and the permissions on the log file it creates. If there was sensitive info there and anybody could view it, it could be an issue.

Comment: @Alex If filenames have unreadable characters, both `for i in $(find` and worse `find ... | xargs rm` can iterate over invalid file names (and I think the second one can end up removing wrong files !). Better use zero-terminated streams. Also `ls -la $file` has an unquoted argument that can mess up more and `ls` output acts differently on different systems, that's why you should parse it's output. Use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check for most obvious shell mistakes.

Comment: Seconded on the shellcheck - that is an excellent tool and I always run all my scripts through it, however simple they are.